On the relationship between spectral clustering and linear subspace modeling
Spectral clustering centers on the embedding of a graph with $d$ nodes, first into $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ via the graph Laplacian $\boldsymbol L=\boldsymbol D - \boldsymbol A$, and then into $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ by stacking $k$ orthonormal eigenvectors of $\boldsymbol L$ corresponding to its $k$ smallest eigenvalues. It then applies $k$-means to the resulting embedding
Equivalently, one can extract the $k$ eigenvectors of $\boldsymbol I-\boldsymbol L$ corresponding to its largest eigenvalues. At that point, we may as well shift the spectrum in order to maintain positive semidefiniteness by considering $\boldsymbol L_{\sigma}=\sigma \boldsymbol I - \boldsymbol L$ for sufficiently large $\sigma > 0$, whence the spectral decomposition yielding the desired embedding is also a singular value decomposition $$\boldsymbol  L_{\sigma}= \boldsymbol  U \boldsymbol  \Sigma \boldsymbol  V^{\top}.$$The least-squares-optimal rank-$k$ approximation to $\boldsymbol L_{\sigma}$ is known to be given by the $k$-truncated singular value decomposition $$\boldsymbol  L_{\sigma} \approx \boldsymbol  U_{k} \boldsymbol  \Sigma_{k} \boldsymbol  V^{\top}, \ (*)$$
where $\boldsymbol U_{k}$ consists of the first $k$ columns of $\boldsymbol U$. This is precisely the embedding used by spectral clustering. Since Euclidean $k$-means is invariant under orthogonal transformation of the input space, really any orthonormal eigenbasis of $\operatorname{span}(\boldsymbol U_{k})$ should do for spectral cluster — i.e., what matters is the optimal $k$-dimensional linear subspace modeling the $d$ node embeddings given by the columns of $\boldsymbol L_\sigma$, not any particular (eigen)basis of that subspace.
It is tempting, then, to ask: under what conditions is $(*)$ an equality — that is, when is $\boldsymbol L_{\sigma}$ truly rank-$k$?
The only example I can come up with is to let $G$ be a graph on $k$ disjoint cliques, each of size $s$, with Laplacian $\boldsymbol L=\boldsymbol D - \boldsymbol A$. Then (I think) we know that $\lambda(\boldsymbol L)=(\overbrace{0,\dots,0}^{k \text{ times}}, \overbrace{s, \dots, s}^{d-k \text{ times}})$, whence $\boldsymbol L_{s}=s\boldsymbol I - \boldsymbol L$ will be rank-$k$. Are there any others?
